# Flex 4.5 Spark DataGrid - Detect column clicked in selectionChange handler

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5, flex-spark

I have a spark datagrid with `selectionMode="multipleRows"`.

I have three columns in the datagrid.

I don't want the row selection to happen when the user's click falls on the third column of a row.

The row selection should happen only when one of the first two columns is clicked.

How do I achieve this? There is a `selectionChanging` event for the datagrid, but the `GridSelectionEvent` object received in the handler does not seem to provide any information about the column on which the click happened.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself. I am not sure if this is a bug in the spark DataGrid. The following is definitely a hack and not clean.

In the `grid_mouseDownHandler` function in the `DataGrid.as` file, there is a line:

> ```
> const columnIndex:int = isCellSelection ? event.columnIndex : -1;
> ```

This line is causing the `columnIndex` to be set as `-1` if the `selectionMode` of the `DataGrid` is anything other than `GridSelectionMode.SINGLE_CELL` or `GridSelectionMode.MULTIPLE_CELLS`. As I mentioned in the original question, I need my datagrid to have a `selectionMode` of `GridSelectionMode.MULTIPLE_ROWS`.

I sub-classed the DataGrid and re-implemented the `grid_mouseDownHandler` (basically copy-pasted the whole function). I changed only the above line to always assign the `columnIndex` to `event.columnIndex`.

(I also had to copy some more functions which were referenced by the `grid_mouseDownHandler` over to my sub-class because those functions were protected or mx_internal. (`toggleSelection`, `extendSelection`, `isAnchorSet`)

Then, in the `selectionChanging` event handler, I could just do the following:

> ```
> if( 2 == event.selectionChange.columnIndex )
> {
>     event.preventDefault();
> }
> ```

I realize that this is not a clean solution, but it is the best I could think of. Maybe someone can suggest a better solution?